# What happens when a bounty expires?

Tags: support, bounty

When a bounty is started on a question, and it expires without getting any attention, what happens to it?

Does the person who asked question lose the points, or are the points awarded to him again?

Comment: Yes, it is lost. The points are what you paid for "advertising" the question.

Comment: How would someone know that his question is duplicate , if he doesn't / unable to find it on stackoverflow. This is not fair guys.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (emphasis added):

> All bounties are paid for up front and **non-refundable under any circumstances**.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, **no bounty is awarded to anyone.**

That means the reputation posts you lost won't be returned. Note that you already lose them when *placing* the bounty, not when the bounty is *awarded*.

Comment: `no bounty is awarded to anyone.`, will the bounty stay there until it fulfill `minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen` or it just gone after `within 7 days (plus the grace period)`?

Comment: @GMsoF I think it is just gone forever, then.